# Split a list in sublists by a logic criterion

Tags: python, list-comprehension, conditional-statements

I have a list where each element can be a number or one of two different strings (let's call 'a' and 'b'). I want to split the list in three lists: the list of numbers, the list of 'a' and the list of 'b'.

I can do it using a conditional list comprehension:

```
mixlist=[1,2,'a',3,'b','a']
numlist=[el for el in mixlist if type(el)==int]
alist=[el for el in mixlist if el=='a']
blist=[el for el in mixlist if el=='b']
```

but it leads to run several times on mixlist. Probably I can do better, but I do not know a short way to do it running over mixlist only one time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it straight forward, like this

```
numlist, alist, blist = [], [], []
for item in mixlist:
    if item == "a":
        alist.append(item)
    elif item == "b":
        blist.append(item)
    else:
        numlist.append(item)
```

Or you can shorten it a little bit, like this

```
numlist, alist, blist = [], [], []
d = {"a": alist, "b": blist}
for item in mixlist:
    d.get(item, numlist).append(item)
```

`dict.get` method will return the value corresponding to the key. But when the key is not found, it will return the default value passed as the second parameter. So, in our case, if the key is `a` or `b` we will get corresponding `alist` or `blist`. If neither of them, then we will get `numlist` and we append `item` to it.

**Edit:** You can slightly improve the straight forward way like this

```
mixlist = [1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', 'a']

numlist, alist, blist = [], [], []
nappend, aappend, bappend = numlist.append, alist.append, blist.append

for item in mixlist:
    if item == "a":
        aappend(item)
    elif item == "b":
        bappend(item)
    else:
        nappend(item)
```

Comment: Nitpick: `d.get(item, numlist)` makes the defaults for items that aren't `'a'`/`'b'` - eg, `'c'` will end up in there and it's not a number (something the OPs code wouldn't do as it's an implicit type check)... I'd  go for declaring `d = {'a': [], 'b': [], int: []}` and use `d[int if instance(item, int) else item].append(item)` and unpack the lists from the dict after if required...

Comment: I've deleted the first comment once I fully understood the 'dictionary' solution. That's because it possible to run as list comprehension.

Comment: thefourtheye: The `nappend = numlist.append, aappend = alist.append, bappend = blist.append` line in your update raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: thefourtheye: Good, looks like it'll actual work now—although I think `nappend, aappend, bappend = numlist.append, alist.append, blist.append` would have been better...

Comment: @martineau Yup, that would be much better. Updated the answer with that now :-)

Comment: @Jon Clements: While your suggestion is clever, one thing about it is it  updates the list values of dictionary `d` resulting in `{'a': ['a', 'a'], 'b': ['b'], <class 'int'>: [1, 2, 3]}` which isn't quite the same as creating and populating 3 variables named `numlist`, `alist`, and `blist`.

Comment: @user2988577: The only thing wrong about making the 'dictionary' version a list comprehension is that `append()` returns `None`, do the resulting list would be `[None, None, None, None, None, None]` and using a list comp like that only for the side-effect of executing a `for` loop is considered by many to be a poor programming practice (and adds wasted overhead).